# Как заполнить по спирали прямоугольный массив?

Tags: python, массивы

У меня есть массив 3*4, как его заполнить по спирали?
Всё что находил связано с заполнением квадратного.
Пишу на Python3

Массив создаю так:

```
arr = [[[None] for j in range(lenght)] for i in range(weight)]
```

Comment: что значит заполнить по спирали?

Comment: Нужно подумать и переделать заполнение квадратного под прямоугольный. В жизни так: не на каждую задачу можно нагуглить решение, иногда приходится решать самому.

Comment: finally, это когда сначала заполняется верхняя строка, потом правый край, потом нижний, левый.

Comment: Всё, проигралися, не успел я(

Answer (score 2):

Вот функция, которая заполняет квадратный или прямоугольный массив по спирали:

```
def spiralArray(n,m):
    topX=0
    topY=0
    bottomX=m-1
    bottomY=n-1
    k=1;
    array=[[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
    while k<=n*m:
        x=topX
        y=topY
        for x in range(topX,bottomX+1):
            array[y][x]=k
            k=k+1
        topY=topY+1
        if k<=n*m:
            for y in range(topY,bottomY+1):
                array[y][x]=k
                k=k+1
            bottomX=bottomX-1
        if k<=n*m:
            for x in range(bottomX,topX-1,-1):
                array[y][x]=k
                k=k+1
            bottomY=bottomY-1
        if k<=n*m:
            for y in range(bottomY,topY-1,-1):
                array[y][x]=k
                k=k+1
            topX=topX+1

    return array
```